# How to tell which of IP addresses listed by ipconfig /all is localhost

Tags: ipad, localhost, ip-address, fiddler

I am trying to [use fiddler on IPad by connecting it to PC by wireless connection](http://blogs.telerik.com/fiddler/posts/12-12-21/using-fiddler-with-apple-ios-devices) so I could use auto-responder to 'mock' some data.
Tutorial tells me that I should use my machine IP to connect IPad and check if it works, my problem is that I have multiple IP's (or at least it seems that I do).

One candidate would be `192.168.1.23` another `192.168.1.41`
[image]

**How to check which of IP addresses is `localhost`, or they both are pointing to same place?**

Comment: Technically, neither of these is `localhost`, which is `127.0.0.1` and `::1` and neither of those is what you want to configure your iPad to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just 'an' answer not 'the' answer, but this worked for me.

First I navigated to `http://192.168.1.23:8888/` and got

```
Fiddler Echo Service


GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: 192.168.1.23:8888
Proxy-Connection: keep-alive
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.1916.153 Safari/537.36
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language: en-GB,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.6

This page returned a HTTP/200 response 
Originating Process Information: chrome:10568
To configure Fiddler as a reverse proxy instead of seeing this page, see Reverse Proxy Setup
You can download the FiddlerRoot certificate
```

I then navigated to `http://192.168.1.41:8888/`

and got same exact response.

I believe it is safe to assume that both IP addresses are pointing to same place. Not sure if this is always the case, but it is true in mine.

It would appear that [I am using multihoming.](http://compnetworking.about.com/od/tcpip/g/multihoming.htm)